# How moq File.Delete (IFileSystem) in app MVC Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, moq

My method which work

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteTeam(int id)
    {
        Team team = await teamRepository.DeleteTeamAsync(id);
        var fileToDeletePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/"), team.Path);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileToDeletePath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileToDeletePath);
        }
        if (team != null)
        {
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} был удален", team.Name);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Player");
    }
```

It's my attempt to make a test, but unsuccessful

```
 [TestMethod]
    public async Task CanDeletePlayerAsync()
    {
        //Arrange
        Mock<ITeamRepository> teamsMock = new Mock<ITeamRepository>();

        Team team2 = new Team { Id = 2, Name = "Boston" , Path = "CHi.png" };
        Team team3 = new Team { Id = 3, Name = "Lakers" };

        string fullPath = ("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/");

        var serverMock = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        serverMock.Setup(x => x.MapPath(fullPath)).Returns(@"s:\work");

        var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Server).Returns(serverMock.Object);

        var mockFile = new Mock<IFileSystem>();

        TeamController controller = new TeamController(teamsMock.Object);
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContextMock.Object, new RouteData(), controller);

        teamsMock.Setup(m => m.DeleteTeamAsync(team2.Id)).Returns(Task.FromResult(team2));

        // Act
        ActionResult result = await controller.DeleteTeam(team2.Id);
        mockFile.Verify(x => x.File.Delete(@"s:\work\file.png"));

        //Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
    }
```

I add the funcional to delete image from app if I delete the team. It works perfect, but how make a test by Moq I try some attempts by unsuccessfully.

I have the error message

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.File.Delete("s:\work\file.png")
>   No setups configured.
>   No invocations performed.

how it fix? I have downloaded `IFileSystem` and made a moq but verify have been not work.

Comment: You're not using `IFileSystem` in your actual code, so that's why the verification is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious solution would be to wrap your File.Delete Call in Custom Class, which implements a Custom interface, For example,

```
public interface IFileOperations
{
    void Delete(string path);
}
```

For your System Operations, you can create a wrapper class.

```
public class SystemFileOperations:IFileOperations
{
    public void Delete(string path)
    {
        File.Delete(path);
    }
}
```

Now you can alter your original code to ensure SystemFileOperations is injected at all places where you would require IFileOperations.Delete.

```
private IFileOperations _fileOperations;
public ControllerName(IFileOperations operations)
{
_fileOperations = operations;
}
```

Following line would be then replaced

```
System.IO.File.Delete(fileToDeletePath);
```

with

```
 _fileOperations.Delete(fileToDeletePath);
```

And for mocking , you could

```
var mock = new Mock<IFileOperations>();
mock.Verify(x=>x.Delete(path),Times.AtLeastOnce());
```

Please note that in your case, due to usage of File.Exists, you might have to mock that as well following the same pattern if you desire so

Comment: I made like you said to me but I took the same problem Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.Delete("s:\work\CHi.png")

Comment: Could you share how your controller constructor or place where you have injected IFileOperation look like

Comment: problem with that part of code 

`if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileToDeletePath))`

if i delete it all work, but i try to make by repository doesn't help

Comment: @remk93 You need to add it to the interface, an exist method. You need to mock that as well.

Comment: I change the verify to the strongly Setup and it working
` SetupfileMock.Setup(x => x.Exists(returnPath)).Returns(true);
            fileMock.Setup(x => x.Delete(returnPath));`

And i dont understand why the verify doesn't work?